# How to edit web part properties in the UI that was added in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

Let's say I create a custom page layout in SPD. Instead of adding a web part zone I add a web part (let's say content query web part) in the layout. When I go to a page using that layout I can see the web part but if I go site actions -> edit page I can't change the properties of the web part.

What I would like to do is to add a content query web part at a certain place in a layout and then let the users be able to edit the web part through the UI and for example change which list the web part should get the data from.

If I only add a web part zone and 20 pages needs to be created then the user has to add the web part 20 times and select list 20 times etc.

Is what I try to achieve possible without writing custom web parts with custom properties?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I can see that there is a property called BrowserDesignMode set to false but I can't change it to true.

Comment: Is there any way to insert the WebPart in the Web Part zone in the layout?
I had a scenario where I needed to automatically insert webparts in WebPart zones inside Site Pages, and did that through XML (or via code).
I think in order for the WebPart editor to be available it needs to be inside a Web Part zone.

Comment: The BrowserDesignMode property is a red herring - its an obsolete read-only property for determining of the web part is in design mode or not at runtime (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.browserdesignmode.aspx). I've got the same problem, I have no solution yet :(